# Issues converting RGB to image with correct size

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library, rgb

I have data of RGB values for an image of size 1280x720 in a list that looks like this:

```
[[102, 107, 111],
 [101, 106, 110],
 [100, 105, 109],
 [100, 105, 109],
 [101, 106, 109],
 [103, 108, 111],
 [105, 110, 113],
             ...]
```

I got this data from `Image.getdata()` and converted it to a 2d list for separate reasons (this list is called `all_data`). However, when I try to set the size to what I want using the code below, I get a `TypeError: too many data entries`.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

image_out = Image.new(mode = "RGB", size = (1280, 720))
image_out.putdata(all_data)
image_out.show()
```

This is probably not the right way of doing this, so if anyone has any knowledge of where I should go with it, please let me know. As expected, I have data for 1280*720 pixels that should be in the order that `Image.getdata()` puts them in (from what I'd assume, it is a standard left to right and top to bottom rendering).

Comment: Could you get the length of all_data? If the output of len(all_data) is not 1280*720, then we know there's a problem creating the array. If it is, then there's a problem with how the Image is getting filled.

Comment: @shadow-kris Yes, i can confirm len(all_data) is 921600 (or 1280*720).

Comment: That's funny, I get a completely different error: `TypeError: color must be int or tuple`.

Comment: @MarkRansom what list are you using because that error shouldn't come with all int data?

Comment: PythonMan1029: Please provide a [mre] (i.e. much smaller image and put all the data in your question).

Comment: I tried a really simplified example with only 1x1 pixel, and I made up my own color for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the image library requires rgb data to be tuples, not a list. I wasn't able to find this explicitly mentioned in the documentation, but verified it through my own testing. All of the documentation examples also use either ints or tuples (https://hhsprings.bitbucket.io/docs/programming/examples/python/PIL/Image__class_Image.html#id1)

The conversion from a list of lists to a list of tuples can be done by this line:

```
tuples = [tuple(x) for x in all_data]
```

In context:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

image_out = Image.new(mode = "RGB", size = (1280, 720))
tuples = [tuple(x) for x in all_data]
image_out.putdata(tuples)
image_out.show()
```